# 'White lotus' referred to in sikshastakam

Tags: prayer, nama

In the sikshastakam, the word karaiva is translated into English as "white lotus". I am curious to know the specific, scientific name of the actual karaiva.

It's significant for this: lotuses only bloom in the day not the night. Lotuses are sometimes mistaken for lilies, which can bloom in the night.

If we look at the context of the sikshastakam, "Oh Name, stream down in moonlight on the lotus heart opening its cup of knowledge to Thyself" it is asking for the Holy Name to take control of the lotus, opening it where it would otherwise not - that through the Lord's mercy, not what we do, God grants us the knowledge of true love for Him.

If the correct context is the lily and not the lotus, it makes for another line in the prayer but without the above meaning.

Jai Sri Mā

Answer (score 1):

The terminology for translating the omnipresent names for lotuses and water-lilies in Sanskrit literature continues to be problematic due to using outdated works or works suffering from unclear botanical terminology.

Indian poets clearly distinguished b/w water-lilies (*Nymphaea*) and lotuses (*Nelumbium*). Below that level, only the color of the blossoms mattered to poets. Since, there is botanically only one kind of lotus in India, i.e. *Nelumbo nucifera*, the translation and identification is easy. Terms like *paṅkaja, abja, kamala, padma* etc. can be translated simply as 'lotus' with the colors added, if specified in the text. The color of the blossom here, wouldn't change the identity of the plant. However, the case of water-lilies is pretty different, there are many water-lilies and a mapping of botanical terminology on the Sanskrit names, based only on color doesn't work.

It's important to keep some things in mind before proceeding further. Dictionaries (including Sanskrit dictionaries), encyclopedia are not the correct source of such information, due to them often having unbotanical wrong usages. Lotus are not water lilies, as has been made clear earlier already. And lotus do not blossom at night, only (some) water lilies do so. There is no blue lotus, only a blue water-lily. Names like nīlambuja etc. do not mean blue lotus, but blue water-lily because there is no *blue* lotus technically. And Egyptian lotus is not a lotus as is commonly believed but a water-lily. Usually when we hear red lotus, blue lotus, white lotus etc. in Sanskrit poetry, it mean water lilies of that color rather than lotuses, because the color of Indian lotuses doesn't need to be specified (it is fixed, prominently whitish-pink).

Amarakoṣaḥ by Amarasiṁha at the end of vārivargaḥ of pratham kāṇḍa states:

> syād utpalaṁ kuvalayam atha nīlāmbujanma ca |
> indīvaram ca nile 'smin site kumudakairave || 37 ||

Translation: [The word] *kuvalya* denotes a water lily[of any color] (*utpala*), *nīlāmbujanma* as well as *indīvara* [are used] for the blue [variety], *kumuda* and *kairava* for the white [variety].

Here, *utpala* means a general water-lily of any color, not a lotus. *Nīlambujanma*, which can be taken as generic for *nīlābja* and other synonyms, is indeed a name for a (blue) water-lily. *Kumuda* and *kairava* are clearly said to mean white water-lilies.

In line with this and botanically as well, *Kairava* isn't actually a lotus but a water lily. Also, it blossoms in night (which a lotus doesn't). The scientific name of Indian lotus is actually *Nelumbo nucifera*, the genus being *Nelumbo* and family- *Nelumbonaceae*. On the other hand, *kairava* doesn't belong to the *Nelumbo* genus (lotus). It is of the family *Nymphaeaceae* and genus *Nymphaea*.

Depending on the species and its variety we can give the full scientific names, there are a few water lilies (*Nymphaea*) of white color found in India, such as *Nymphaea alba* and *Nymphaea nouchali var. caerulea*. Both of these are found in white (or whitish) color. *Nymphaea nouchali* is quite commonly seen in India and is known as *nīla kamala*, again to remember it is not a lotus, but a blue water-lily. One of its botanical varieties is *Nymphaea caerulea*, which is a water-lily (of pale bluish-white or white color), found in Assam and Meghalaya. *Nymphaea alba* is usually in white color, and is found in Jammu & Kashmir, Meghalaya, Rajasthan and West Bengal.

Now, our first verse of Śikṣāṣṭakam is as follows:

> ceto-darpaṇa-mārjanaṁ bhava-mahā-dāvāgni-nirvāpaṇaṁ
> śreyaḥ-kairava-candrikā-vitaraṇaṁ vidyā-vadhū-jīvanam
> ānandāmbudhi-vardhanaṁ prati-padaṁ pūrṇāmṛtāsvādanaṁ sarvātma-snapanaṁ
> paraṁ vijayate śrī-kṛṣṇa-saṇkīrtanam

Translation: Śrī Kṛṣṇa *saṅkīrtanam* (congregational chanting of the holy name of Kr̥ṣṇa) cleanses the mirror of the mind, extinguishes the miseries of the blazing fire of worldly life
and spreads the *kairava* (white water-lily) of good fortune by its moonbeams. It is the life of the bride named *vidyā* (knowledge). It swells the sea of *ānanda* (blessedness), gives the full taste of deathless nectar at every step, and bathes the self in all respects.

Clearly, as we see in this verse, *kairava* is shown to have a relation with *candrikā* (moonbeams, moonlight). And it fits with the description of *kairava* given before as a water-lily, since if it was lotus, it wouldn't blossom in moonlight.

**References & Further Reading**

- Śrī Amarkoṣaḥ (Nāmaliṅgānuśāsanam) by Amarsiṁha: https://archive.org/details/AmaraKosha/amara_rasala/page/n3/mode/2up?view=theater
- Hanneder, J. (2002). The Blue Lotus: Oriental Research between Philology, Botany and Poetics? *Zeitschrift Der Deutschen Morgenländischen Gesellschaft, 152*(2), 295–308. http://www.jstor.org/stable/43381086
- Hanneder, J. (2007). Some common errors concerning water-lilies and lotuses. *Indo-Iranian Journal, 50*(2), 161–164. http://www.jstor.org/stable/24664642
- Rau, W. (1954). Lotusblumen. In *Asiatica Festschrift Freidrich Weller* (pp. 505-513). Otto Harrassowitz
- Rau, W. (1986). Poetical Conventions In Indian Kāvya Literature. *Brahmavidyā: Adyar Library Bulletin 50*, S.191-197
- Tripurāri, B.V. (2005). *Śikṣāṣṭakam of Śrī Caitanya*. Mandala Publishing
- Nymphaea alba: https://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/230482
- Nymphaea caerulea: https://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/264154
- Nymphaea nouchali: https://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/230495